# How to draw an outline with bpy gpu module?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, gpu, gpu-module

is there a simple & efficient way to draw the outline of a mesh with the [gpu](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html) module ? the script should be able to control the width of the outline line

Defining outline:
"*A line indicating the outer contours or boundaries of an object or figure.*"

Example of an outline:
[image]

Nice article on how outlines are made in games:
https://alexanderameye.github.io/notes/rendering-outlines/

Comment: i searched on gooogle for sample images on "outline" i couldn't find anything to help me understand. did you mean bounding box? perhaps an image of, say suzanne object with an outline would help.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie In video games at least outlines are done by drawing an object in a solid color and dilating the 2D render, then drawing the actual rendered object on top of it. See https://answers.unity.com/questions/1292087/how-to-make-shining-highlighted-outline-to-a-gameo.html for an example. I agree that a visual example would be helpful here to know exactly what you are looking for as an effect

Comment: ohhhh ok yeah that sounds about right, that's probably what the OP meant i guess. so basically the same orange/yellow outline when i select an object in blender

Comment: @DB3D thanks for adding an image example. i'd be interested to see an answer for this!

Comment: how outline are done in games
https://alexanderameye.github.io/notes/rendering-outlines/
i think it is quite hard to do this in `bpy`

Comment: maybe this add-on helps you, and because it is an add-on the code should there, shouldn't it? but i assume that it is not (!) for gpu....

Comment: @Chris, which addon?

Comment: i am sorry, forgot to paste the link, here it is: https://github.com/azeemba/blender-add-outline

Comment: @Chris, this only but add a material to objects, the code is not actually drawing any outlines

Comment: Ah ok. Didn’t know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a *partial* solution from [Carbon2](https://github.com/uhlik)

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
import numpy as np
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


vertex_shader = '''
in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec4 color;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

uniform vec3 camera_location;
uniform float factor1;
uniform float factor2;

out vec4 fcolor;
void main()
{
    
    vec3 pos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
    vec3 nor = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
    
    float d = distance(pos, camera_location) * factor1;
    vec3 offset = nor * vec3(d);
    vec3 p = pos + offset;
    //p = pos;
    
    // hmmm?
    //vec3 n = nor * vec3(0.0);
    //nor = nor * vec3(0.0);
    
    vec3 dir = p - camera_location;
    dir = normalize(dir) * vec3(factor2);
    p = p + dir;
    
    //gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    //gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(p, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(p, 1.0);
    //fcolor = color * vec4(offset, 1.0);
    fcolor = color;
    //fcolor = color * vec4(dir / vec3(factor2), 1.0);
}
'''
fragment_shader = '''
in vec4 fcolor;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    fragColor = blender_srgb_to_framebuffer_space(fcolor);
}
'''


def draw(self, context, ):
    gpu.state.depth_test_set('LESS')
    
    self.shader.bind()
    self.shader.uniform_float("model", self.o.matrix_world)
    self.shader.uniform_float("view", bpy.context.region_data.view_matrix)
    self.shader.uniform_float("projection", bpy.context.region_data.window_matrix)
    
    cl = bpy.context.region_data.view_matrix.inverted().translation
    self.shader.uniform_float("camera_location", cl)
    self.shader.uniform_float("factor1", 0.01)
    self.shader.uniform_float("factor2", 50.0)
    
    self.batch.draw(self.shader)
    
    gpu.state.depth_test_set('NONE')


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = ""
    
    def prepare(self, ):
        me = self.o.data
        me.calc_loop_triangles()
        
        vs = np.zeros((len(me.vertices) * 3, ), dtype=np.float32, )
        me.vertices.foreach_get('co', vs)
        vs.shape = (-1, 3, )
        ns = np.zeros((len(me.vertices) * 3, ), dtype=np.float32, )
        me.vertices.foreach_get('normal', ns)
        ns.shape = (-1, 3, )
        fs = np.zeros((len(me.loop_triangles) * 3, ), dtype=np.int32, )
        me.loop_triangles.foreach_get('vertices', fs)
        fs.shape = (-1, 3, )
        cs = np.full((len(me.vertices), 4), (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), dtype=np.float32, )
        
        shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(vertex_shader, fragment_shader, )
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"position": vs, "normal": ns, "color": cs, }, indices=fs, )
        return shader, batch
    
    def tag_redraw(self):
        for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
            for area in window.screen.areas:
                if(area.type == 'VIEW_3D'):
                    area.tag_redraw()
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("start")
    
    def __del__(self):
        print("end")
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle_3d, 'WINDOW')
            self.tag_redraw()
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        else:
            pass
        
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.o = context.active_object
        self.shader, self.batch = self.prepare()
        self._handle_3d = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (self, context, ), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW', )
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        self.tag_redraw()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.view3d.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: why only partial?

Comment: because there is no support for many objects, handling accurate behavior for back/front drawing is challenging

Comment: i tried it, it works actually pretty well. whenever i add a new mesh to the object and run the code, it works perfectly. nice work!

Answer (score 1):

The following script will draw the outline of the selected object in `bpy.context.object`. Make sure you [`Apply Transforms`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) before you run the script:

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

o = bpy.context.object
mesh = o.data
coords = [v.co + o.location for v in mesh.vertices]
indices = [(e.vertices[0], e.vertices[1]) for e in mesh.edges]
shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(
shader, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=indices)

def draw():
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 0, 0, 1))
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

Here's the outline of the [Suzanne monkey object](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/software/animation-software/blender/meet-suzanne-the-blender-monkey-142918/). Please see the documentation on [`GPU Module`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I believe you misinterpreted what an outline is, am i wrong?

Comment: oh i was thinking of wireframe sorry. hmmm i'm not sure what you mean. do you mean like the bounding box? maybe an image would help with the description of outline "*A line indicating the outer contours or boundaries of an object or figure.*"

Comment: anyway, don't worry...both answers are incorrect :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not a script, but you could tweek this shader.[image]